# What technology or framework or API do I have to use for this app?

Tags: flutter, react-native, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, live-streaming

I have to build mobile app that can support Live Portrait with photo.

Live Portrait means the technology that enables to make video from photo, make faces in photo act lively. I have full-searched google but still I can't find appropriate data.

I have to use hybrid mobile app framework such as React Native, Flutter for my app.
Here are questions.

1. Is is possible to make app that can support Live Portrait with Flutter or React Native?
2. Is there any API or service or framework for Live Portrait?

I would be appreciated for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add interactive content on images, then you can use python for build face detector features and react-native to create interactive part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Usama. Can you let me know detail about that technology? Should I integrate Python in my react-native app or in my back-end?

Comment: https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/